# How to take screenshot in flutter during video call?

Tags: flutter, dart, agora.io

I'm currently using agora SDK for a flutter video call. During the video call, I need to take a screenshot. Only on the video call screen, the screenshot is black and on other screens the screenshots are fine.
By using RenderRepaintBoundary I can't able to take a screenshot,

**Code used to take the screenshot:**

```
Future<void> _capturePng() async {
    try {
      RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
          _globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
      ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
      ByteData byteData =
          await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
      var pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
      final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(pngBytes);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }  }  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RepaintBoundary(
        key: _globalKey,
        child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            body: GestureDetector(
                onDoubleTap: () => _capturePng(),
                child: Screenshot(
                  controller: screenshotController,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        _viewRows(),
                        _toolbar(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ))));
}
```

issue screenshot:

[image]

working fine screenshot:

[image]

[Agora SDK link](https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine)

replace this below code with flutter main.dart sample

[videocall.zip](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Flutter-Quickstart/files/4273568/call.zip)

Agora rtc version:agora_rtc_engine: ^1.0.7

Also tried using this plugin:  screenshot: ^0.1.1
but still, the issue occurs

Comment: did you find an answer? i believe issue is in the video. i have same issue tsalking screenshot of a video.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code for screenshoot is right. The problem may be in where you put the `RepaintBoundary`. In general, the `key` provided in `RepaintBoundary` will be able to screenshot it's whole child hierarchy. So I think the solution is to put your `Widget` which renders your live video feed inside `RepaintBoundary` as child. e.g

```
Widget build(context){
   return RepaintBoundary(
      key: _yourGlobalKey,
      child: _yourLiveVideoFeedWidget
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there’s a problem with your screenshot method declaration, this is the syntax that needs to be followed:

ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController();